# How can I use an absolute path for the razor-engine to search under?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, razorengine

I have multiple projects that are written on the top of ASP.NET MVC framework. Each of these projects use common views and editor-templates. Thus, I have to duplicate the common views like editor-templates and master-layout into every project on my local machine.

Instead of duplicating views, is there a way to include an absolute path instead of using `~` to determine the views' path when the app is running locally?

In another words, instead on using something like `~/CustomViews/Shared/{0}.cshtml` is there a way to use `c:\\MyProjects\\CommonViews\\Views\\Shared\\EditorTemplates\\{0}.cshtml` to tell razor-engine where to search?

I would only include the absolute path if my running environment is dev or running on a localhost.

I tried to create a my own engine which extends the [RazorViewEngine](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/4e40cdef9c8a8226685f95ef03b746bc8322aa92/src/System.Web.Mvc/RazorViewEngine.cs) class

```
public class CustomViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public CustomViewEngine()
        : base()
    {
        ViewLocationFormats = GetGlobalViews();
    }

    public string[] GetGlobalViews()
    {
        var views = new List<string>();

        if (Running on localhost...)
        {
            var baseDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~"));
            var root = baseDirectory.Parent.Parent.Parent;
            var viewsPath = Path.Combine(root.FullName, "CommonViews", "Views");

            if (Directory.Exists(viewsPath))
            {
                // include the Views directory
                views.Add(viewsPath.ToString() + "/{1}/{0}.cshtml");

                // include the Views/Shared directory
                var sharedViewsPath = Path.Combine(viewsPath, "Shared");
                views.Add(sharedViewsPath.ToString() + "/{1}/{0}.cshtml");

                // include the Views/Shared/EditorTemplates directory
                var editorTemplatesViewsPath = Path.Combine(sharedViewsPath, "EditorTemplates");
                views.Add(editorTemplatesViewsPath.ToString() + "/{1}/{0}.cshtml");
            }
        }

        return views;
    }
}
```

Then in the `Application_Start` method of my app I added the following code to use the `CustomViewEngine`.

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine());
```

But when the system error because the view does not exists, none of my absolute bath is listed as it was searched

Note: I am not worrying about deployment issues or production environment issues I just want this to work locally.

Comment: Why would you want to hard-code the views to a very specific path??  That's a very bad idea in almost all circumstances.  It sounds to me like you want a [multi-tenant system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy), not multiple applications.

Comment: I just want to be able to share my common editor templates across my project locally. I am open for better idea other that "copying" and "pasting" common views in all of my projects

Comment: So for example you have a single `string` editor template you want shared across multiple applications?  (In other words, you do NOT have multiple `string` editor templates in any of your applications)

Comment: @ErikPhilips yes that is right. I have an editor-template for every time that I use in every project.